# qooxdoo mobile list view item expandable

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there any possibility to make mobile list view item behave like collapsible. I would like implement special button or something that vertically expands the current item to show/reveal more info.

Showing dialog does not work for me because it is intrusive to users. This way I would be able to overcome the lack of space on mobile devices and simulate multi-column list view (showing additional column data when expanded) and still be able to use the "selectable" functionality to actually show the content when item is clicked/selected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

You just have to modify (delete, add) the model of your list.If you delete one item out of the qx.data.Array the List updates itself automatically.

Another, more advanced option:

You could write your own qx.Mobile List renderer and use it, for showing a button which shows/hide a list item.

Don't be scared about writing your own renderer, it is quite simple in this case.

Create a class which extends from

```
 qx.ui.mobile.list.renderer.Abstract
```

You may use qx.ui.mobile.list.renderer.Default
as a good starting point (or just copy its content).

You use the List Renderer by overriding the method "createItemRenderer". :

```
var list = new qx.ui.mobile.list.List({
        configureItem: function() {
         [...]
        }

        createItemRenderer: function() {
          return new your.app.renderer.YourListRenderer();
        }
}
```